# Empty Request.Files with MVC 3 file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my markup:

```
<form action="/Customer/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="file" type="file" style="width:300px" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Add Image to S3" />
</form>
```

When I step through the Create action the Request.Files is empty. I've searched and searched and all the advice seems to be about ensuring the enctype is set to "multipart/form-data" which I have already set. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding a `name` attribute to the `input`.  I don't think nameless form items get posted at all.